# Как получить id карточки товара в Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт на WP, на нем установлен плагин Woocommerce. Плиз подскажите пожалуйста как при клике на "добавить товар в корзину" получить id этого товара? Почему именно при клике, так как после этого нужно будет вывести дополнительные данные по товару который добавили в корзину.

Comment: @KAGG Design Спасибо за подсказку, тоже такой вариант рассматриваю, попробую немного ваш код допилить чтоб передать айдишку через аякс ну а дальше уже выведу что мне нужно будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В WooCommerce по умолчанию кнопка добавить в корзину имеет такой вид:

```
<a ... class="... add_to_cart_button" ... data-product_id="347" ... > </a>
```

Поэтому можно использовать примерно такой код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).data('product_id'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Этот код для теста. Выводит в alert ID товара.

Comment: Хм. А `data-product_id` атрибута разве нету? Зачем костыли городить

Comment: @tutankhamun Точно, есть. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться другим пользователям, которые ищут ответ на похожий вопрос.

Comment: @KAGG Design готово!

Comment: @KAGG Design а как мне допустим этот же айди передать через аякс в файл php и там уже его обработать и вывести. Могу форму обработать с инпутами но вот как сам атрибут передать я не в курсе!

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос

Comment: @KAGG Design Задал отдельный вопрос и максимально и с примером своего кода. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830260/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax

Comment: да, вижу... посмотрим