# Как получить данных с клика по ссылке и обработать их через Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Собственно продолжение моего вопроса заданного ранее.
Есть вот такая ссылка на добавление товара в корзину (Woocommerce)

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="ссылка" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="138" data-product_sku="" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart added">Получить</a>
```

Вот я пытаюсь отловить id товара и передать его через Ajax

```
<div id ="result"></div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var that = $(this),
                fData = that.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://",
                dataType:'json',
                data: "param"+JSON.stringify(that),
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#result').html(result)
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

И сам обработчик.

```
if($_POST['param']) {
 $param = json_decode($_POST['param']);
 $row = get_text($param->id);
 echo json_encode($row);
 exit();
}
```

Ребята подскажите что не так делаю, совсем не понимаю джквери немного знаю аякс и то только как обрабатывать формы, наставьте на путь истинный ибо нечего не приходит обратно!=)

Comment: Так ничего не придет. Почитайте хорошую инструкцию на русском https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: В WP лучше делать как положено, через admin-ajax.php, хуками в functions.php, локализацией скрипта wp_localize_script(). В общем, у Кама хорошо расписано.

Comment: @KAGG Design да вот только проблема в том что мой код и на локал-хостен не работает а должен!

Comment: Он и не должен работать. У вас url обработчика - не пойми что. Должно быть http://site.org/папка/file.php. В WP так указывают: http://site.org/admin-ajax.php. Вы читайте инструкцию, научитесь делать всё правильно. Через ж... ещё успеете )

Comment: @KAGG Design 52 а зачем мне сюда выкладывать свои урлы? Надо было вместо http "ссылка" поставить, чтоб не сбивало)Ну в любом случае я переделал и теперь все ок, чуть по другому но работает, так что спс Вам за подсказку она меня натолкнула на мысль а это самое главное.

Comment: В нормальном коде здесь реального урла нет. Только переменная, которая инициализируется через localize_script

Comment: @KAGG Design Я понял переделаю как вы посоветовали!